# Bespoke automatic receipt for specific campaign

Tags: contributions, activities, civirules, scheduled-reminders, receipts

We want to send a bespoke receipt (schedule reminder) to donors who donate to a specific campaign. We are struggling to work out how to link the schedule reminder to contributions to that campaign - we've looked into CiviRules and think we have the extension (but can't find it anywhere on our UI). Are we missing something? Is there a way to set up the trigger email without CiviRules and if CiviRules is the best method to do this, do you have any advice on how to set it up?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1/ if you have civirules installed then
a/ you should see it listed as 'installed' at /civicrm/admin/extensions?reset=1
b/ you should find a CiviRules menu item under Administer (usually gets added at the bottom of the list)

2/ in terms of using it to send out a receipt, if you are wanting to include the amount they you may need an extension such as https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken so that you have 'most recent contribution' value available to insert in to the message (there may be other ways of doing this. just wondering what else might trip you up)

ps i think it would help if you could flesh out in your Q. how bespoke a msg this needs to be, since there is some option in the default receipts to use smarty like IF campaign = goldfish then insert text saying 'thank you for the goldfish food' ELSE 'our goldfish are really hungry'